# How to add label wrap function to NVD3 graph?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

How to add label wrap function by Mike Bostock(https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) to my nvd3 graph?

```
createChart(graph_data, tickValue){
    if (graph_data) {
        var chart;

        nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
                    .reduceXTicks(false)   //If 'false', every single x-axis tick label will be rendered.
                    .rotateLabels(-45)      //Angle to rotate x-axis labels.
                    .showControls(true)   //Allow user to switch between 'Grouped' and 'Stacked' mode.
                    .groupSpacing(0.15)    //Distance between each group of bars.
                ;
            chart.xAxis
                .tickFormat(function (i) {
                    return tickValue[i];
                });

            chart.yAxis
                .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

            d3.select('#chart1')
                .datum(graph_data)
                .call(chart);

            return chart;
        });
    } else {
        return <div/>
    }
}
```

`tickValue[i]` return strings like "Call to get Details, Preferences, and suggest Cars".

I need to wrap this string so that it can fit my graph.

I tried using wrap function(https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) but am not able to do so as it is for d3 and not nvd3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In nvd3 version 1.8.5 (I don't know about older versions) this is already implemented. Just use

```
wrapLabels: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've used [Mike Bostock’s Wrapping long labels](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) example with the question.

I've used an example that I answered in a different post. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/50ba3yeo/) a working version of the example.

Add margins to the chart to make it pretty:

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart().margin({
  top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 100
});
```

Finally I selected all the `xAxis` ticks on the chart and applied [Mike Bostock’s Wrapping long labels](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) `function wrap` to it. Add the following code to the bottom of your chart.

```
d3.selectAll(".nv-x.nv-axis .tick text").each(function(i, e) {
  var text = d3.select(this),
    words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
    word, line = [], lineNumber = 0,
    lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
    y = text.attr("y"),
    dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
    tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");

  while (word = words.pop()) {
    line.push(word);
    tspan.text(line.join(" "));
    // TDOD : Make 80 a dynamic value based on the bar width/height
    if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > 80) {
      line.pop();
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      line = [word];
      tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
    }
  }
});
```

Final output
[image]

Hope it helps